# How are zencart passwords encrypted in Sql Server?

Tags: security, zen-cart, password-storage

I have set up a zencart on my web server and the passwords for admin functions are encrypted (or obfuscated in some way) in the sql database associated with zencart - can anyone tell me the extent of this encryption? I want to know if someone who managed to get hold of the database would be able to get access to the data in the password section of the database or whether I would be protected against that specific part of the data becoming public by its encryption.

If it is encrypted, how is it encrypted and how easily can they decrypt it?

It is a default zen cart set up.

Kind regards

Comment: Are these really passwords to a SQL Login/Account?  Or are these zencart application passwords?

Comment: Zen Cart app passwords stored in a SQL database (as far as I can tell)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passwords in ZenCart are stored as MD5 hash created for a salt + password. The format stored in the SQL database is MD5Hash:Salt.

Salting the password before creating the hash prevents users with access to the user table from reverse engeneering the password with help from rainbow tables. So, you are secure, but it could be better if a SHA-2 algorithm was used.

With PHP you can create data for storage with this code:

> $hashedPassword = md5($salt.$password).':'.$salt;

Comment: Thank you! You clearly know a lot about this. Can you tell me if they can get hold of this "salt" elsewhere and reverse the encryption using it?

PS you say the MD5 is not as safe as SHA-2, how long would it take someone to decrypt it by brute force as a salted MD5?

Comment: The purpose of salts are to prevent users from using rainbowtables to look up the password. Rainbowtables are in fact a large database with pre-calculated hashes for a large number of character combinations. When salting a password with random characters before calculating, rainbow tables will be useless. Salts are not secure, and is store in the ZenCart database after the colon in the same column as the hash are stored (read colon separated). See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Collision_vulnerabilities for information about why MD5 is less secure than SHA-2 algorithm.

Comment: Thank you, what I also have read in the last couple of hours has substantiated what you said. Is there a way to protect the salt in the Zen Cart database/another alternative way to protect the password or is it a limitation of the program?

Comment: PS to correct myself where I said "reverse the encryption" I was wrong, I should have said reverse the hash, as a hash is not encryption. I now realise a hash is one way only anyway.

Comment: I think there is no reason to encrypt the salt, since the purpose of salt is to prevent use of rainbow tables to retreive the password. When you check the entered password in ZenCart you will retreive the password column, take bytes after the colon (which is the salt), and add the salt before the entered password and calculate the MD5 hash. If the calculated hash matches the stored hash (bytes before the colon), the entered password is correct, otherwise a wrong password was entered.

Answer (score 1):

Newer versions of ZenCart use the SHA256 hashing algorithm with a random salt (even though for some unknown reason the variable is called "password"):

```
function zen_encrypt_password_new($plain)
{
  $password = '';
  for($i = 0; $i < 40; $i ++) {
    $password .= zen_rand();
  }
  $salt = hash('sha256', $password);
  $password = hash('sha256', $salt . $plain) . ':' . $salt;
  return $password;
}
```

(from version 1.5.4 - `includes/functions/password_funcs.php`)